# intent.getStringExtra must not be null kotlin

Tags: android-intent, kotlin

I want to passing data with intent extra from fragment to activity, Usually I use anko common intent from activity to activity

```
startactivity<secondActivity>("values" to "123")
```

but in my case, I want to passing data from fragment to activity like this

```
activity?.startactivity<secondActivity>("values" to "123")
```

when I want to get String Extra in my activity,

```
val values: String = ""
val intent = intent
values = intent.getStringExtra("values")
```

I get Error

```
intent.getstringextra must not be null
```

Do you have a solution for my case? because I do that to get extra from activity to activity no problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you've declared `values` variable as **not nullable** i.e. the compiler will:

- check that you yourself should not assign `null` or possibly `null` values
- insert runtime checks whenever necessary to achieve safety

The [`Intent.getStringExtra`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)) may return `null` and thus the compiler is complaining.

You can declare the `values` variable as possibly `null` and handle that case in code e.g.:

```
val values: String? = intent.getStringExtra("values")
if(values == null){
   finish()
   return;
}
```

Or assign a default value in case the intent does not have `values` extra:

```
val values = intent.getStringExtra("values") ?: "Default values if not provided"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use kotlin Null Safety. if its null it wont assign value

```
 var values: String = ""
 val intent = intent
 intent.getStringExtra("values")?.let {
   values=it
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you declare that values can't be null, if you want values can be null, you should declare it like this

```
var values:String? = null
```

Or if you want to get a default value when values are null, you can do something like this

```
values = if (intent.getStringExtra("values")==null) "" else intent.getStringExtra("values")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get data from a widget, make sure that you converted it to String.

> val content: **String** = YourTextWidget.text.**toString()**